# How to associate post field with user email? [METEOR]

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-autoform

I have a posts model that I have published and is working fine. However, I have added the following field via simpleSchemas plugin:

```
userEmail: {
  type: String,
  autoValue: function() {
    if (this.isInsert) {
      return Meteor.user().email;
    } else if (this.isUpsert) {
      return {$setOnInsert: Meteor.user().email};
    } else {
      this.unset();
    }
  }
}
```

When I have this enabled, submit forms don't work, but don't raise any errors. Am I perhaps calling on `Meteor.user().email` incorrectly? How do I associate the userEmail field with the email of the user who created the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntaxis is.

```
Meteor.user().emails[0].address
```

Answer (score -1):

The default Meteor.users collection stores emails in an array (To support multiple emails). Something like `return Meteor.user().emails[0].address` should work.

Comment: hi @Curtis the correct syntaxis is `Meteor.user().emails[0].address` not `Meteor.user().email[0]` you are missing `emails` and `.address`